# Can not find appropriate method for wrapping a block with css-shadows

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

I have the common case with a **background wrapper** and **floated columns** inside. Like this (though column tags may vary):

```
<div class="wrap fx-lift">
   <figure class="col"></figure>
   <aside class="col"></aside>
</div>
```

Everything went fine ( `.wrap {overflow: hidden;}` ) until the design was decorated with **shadows** aka "lifted corners" (`.fx-lift`). Those shadows are set through `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, by applying the following class to wrappers (there're few of them across the page).

```
.fx-lift:before, .fx-lift:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
   left: ...
   bottom: ...
   box-shadow: ...

   etc.
}
```

So, this has brought few restrictions: no more usage of **`overflow: hidden;`** on `.wrap` because  it hides the shadows.

The **clearfix** `clear: both;`, applied to `.wrap:after` also makes no sense, because of the absolute positioning in shadow's rule.

**Floating** the `.wrap` solves this problem partially, but creates two more. *First*, the width collapses in some cases; width can't be given a defined value (in px or %) - it varies depending on parents', that also have strict paddings in 'px'. *Second*, again no spare place for "clear: both;" after the floated wrapper.

So, my "wrapping skill" ends up with adding **something like `<br clear="both">`** in the bottom of `div.wrap`. Actually, it solves everything, but - yukk, you know :) - is this the only way left to wrap the elements? Or am I just missing something else?

http://jsfiddle.net/D5hUu/703/

In fiddle there's the <br>-method enabled. Other are turned off by comments in CSS. Try and see, hope you'll have a better idea.

Comment: Is it possible that you create a jsFiddle with your problem?

Comment: Indeed, you're right. Here it is [http://jsfiddle.net/D5hUu/703/](http://jsfiddle.net/D5hUu/703/)